# How do I get the program to request for input for the string "course" before they print out the while/if statement

Tags: c++

***How do i do that without switching the sequence of asking the questions in my program? I would like to get their age, before asking about the course. However, once the age is keyed in, the program automatically proceeds to print the while/if statement.***

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int age; //Declares the variable "age"
    string name;
    string course;


    cout << "Hi\n"; //Prints out "Hello World"
    cout << "What is your name? ";
        getline(cin, name);
    cout << "\nHow old are you ? ";  //Ask the user their age
        cin >> age; //Records the value entered by user
    cout << "What course are you picking up in university ? ";
        getline(cin, course);

    //If number entered is smaller than 0, print the following message
    while (age < 0 ) {
        cout << "\nYou can't be younger than 0 years old.";
        cout << "\nPlease try again";

        cout << "\n\nHow old are you ? ";
        cin >> age;
    }

    //If number entered is larger than 100, print the following message
    if (age > 100) {
        cout << "\nYou are such a blessed person !\n\n";
    }

    //If number entered is between 1 and 99, print the following message
    if (age > 1 && age < 99) {
        cout << "Your name is " << name << " ,and you are " << age << " years old.";
        cout << "\n You are planning on taking " << course << " in university.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move the course question into the `if(1 < age < 99)` statement?

Answer (score 1):

If `getline()` is used after `cin >>`, the `getline()` sees this newline character as leading whitespace, and it just stops reading any further.

Solution:

- Call `cin.ignore()` before calling `getline()`

Or

- Make a dummy call `getline()` to consume the trailing newline character from the `cin>>`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int age; //Declares the variable "age"
    string name;
    string course;


    cout << "Hi\n"; //Prints out "Hello World"
    cout << "What is your name? ";
        getline(cin, name);
    while(true) {
        cout << "\nHow old are you ? ";  //Ask the user their age
        cin >> age; //Records the value entered by user
        if(age>=0)
            break;
        cout << "\nYou can't be younger than 0 years old.\nPlease try again.";
    } 
    cout << "What course are you picking up in university ? ";
        getline(cin, course);

    //If number entered is larger than 100, print the following message
    if (age > 100) {
        cout << "\nYou are such a blessed person !\n\n";
    }

    //If number entered is between 1 and 99, print the following message
    if (age > 1 && age < 99) {
        cout << "Your name is " << name << " ,and you are " << age << " years old.";
        cout << "\n You are planning on taking " << course << " in university.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```